# Closed terminal by mistake while installing new kernel

Tags: apt, upgrade

How do I reinstall it? I was using `sudo apt-get upgrade` and closed terminal before it finished. Now I get this error trying to install anything

```
E: The package linux-image-3.19.0-22-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` the reconfigure an interrupted install

Comment: it did not work,i pasted it in and nothing happend,still give's the error. Am i doing it correctly?

Comment: what output did it give you?

Comment: nothing, i even spammed it tried it in root too

Comment: `sudo` gives the command root access.  Did you paste the part in grey from my comment in a terminal?

Comment: yep sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: ok, next it should have asked for your password since we used sudo. did this happen?

Comment: yeah, i put it inthe password  then nothing happend

Comment: http://gyazo.com/aa2447a4ec3d6effe25a3d7930037fbf

Comment: ok, then try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.19.0-22-generic`

Comment: This worked for me sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-3.19.0-22-generic

Comment: Great!!! I will suggest you add that as an answer to help future users.

Comment: np, and great job in finding the solution and learning.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:do-release-upgrade]? Removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-3.19.0-22-generic –
```

Also for some live support you can try #ubuntu on IRC

https://webchat.freenode.net/